# Код не работает на aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram, conemu

Я писал код на aiogram, python. Когда запускаю .py файл через conemu телеграм бот работает, но когда закрою conemu, бот не работает. Это нормально? Как сделать чтобы мой код работал постоянно?
За ранее спасибо, Лазиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это нормально?

Да, это нормально. Объясню на простом примере: ты сможешь включить любимую передачу на телевизоре, но если ты выключишь телевизор, сериал перестанет показываться на экране :)

> Как сделать чтобы мой код работал постоянно?

Оставь ConEmu или консоль, в котором ты запустил код открытым и не выключай компьютер. Почти шутка.

Если ты хочешь, чтобы бот работал у тебя 24/7, то советую арендовать какой-нибудь сервер у европейских провайдеров (потому что Telegram вполне могут заблокировать в России и я не думаю, что тебе охота будет лишний раз морочиться с прокси серверами). В случае, если ты делаешь бота для себя и тебе необязательно держать его 24/7, то и твой комп сойдет. Только консоль не закрывай)

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный ответ.

Comment: Рад помочь. Если ответ действительно помог, можешь указать его как правильный ответ :)

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.